# How to plot a trajectory of Lorenz attractor system model (SystemModelSimulate - v11.3)

Tags: modeling, system-modeler, version-11.3

I'm using one of the system models provided with *Mathematica* 11.3. (I found it by evaluating `SystemModelExamples[]`.)

```
model = "DocumentationExamples.Simulation.LorenzAttractor";
simModel = SystemModelSimulate[model]
simModel["VariableNames"]
    (* {x', y', z', x, y, z} *)
simModel["StateVariables"]
    (* {x, y, z}  *)
```

I can plot `x`, `y`, `z` together against time `t`:

```
SystemModelPlot[simModel, {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

But how can I plot a trajectory of this system in a 3D space?

I tried

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x, y, z}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

(and the same thing but using names `"x"`, `"y"`, `"z"`), but the result is just an empty plot.

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[simModel[{"x", "y", "z"}, t]], {t, 0, 10}]`? It's in the documentation for `SystemModelSimulationData`.

Comment: Ugh: I missed the first `t`. Still I find this confusing: Why in `SystemModelPlot` is there no explicit `t`, even though the plots of the 3 variables are all against time `t`?

Answer (score 4):

`SystemModelPlot` doesn't do parametric plots. If you want parametric plots, you have to extract the variables from the `SystemModelSimulationData` result.

```
trajectory = simModel[{"x", "y", "z"}, t]
ParametricPlot3D[trajectory, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Or in a single step:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@simModel[{"x", "y", "z"}, t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Answering the comment: `SystemModelPlot` doesn't have an explicit `t`, since it doesn't need one. It always plots against time, so it would be tedious if you would have to specify it for each variable.